# Why Second Monitor Could Not Load the Desktop Background?

Tags: multiple-monitors, desktop-background, 16.10

I've installed Ubuntu 16.10.

When I attached second monitor to my laptop, it works fine but the second monitor's background is black until I change the background while the laptop's background (first monitor) is loaded correctly.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @CelticWarrior: second monitor could not load the desktop background as well as the first monitor.

Comment: Already in th OP and that's a statement, not a question. Try adding "Why is this happening?" and/or "How can I avoid this?", etc., in your own words.

Comment: @CelticWarrior oh thanks for your guide. I've updated it.

Comment: Same problem. It is not possible to set a wallpaper for the second monitor under Kubuntu 16.10.

Comment: @SabreWolfy I think last update of ubuntu fixes this issue, but I'm not sure. try `apt-get update; apt-get upgrade; apt-get dist-upgrade` and then check it.